# Safari - Easy way to open a link in private window?

Tags: macos, safari, shortcut-menu, privacy

Is there an easy way to open links in a private window in Safari in OS X?

With this, I mean copying the link and pasting it in a new private window not as being easy.

In Chrome and Firefox, you can easily open a link in Incognito/Private mode, right clicking on the link and from the context menu, choose Open in an incognito window. This is a feature that I use quite often in my browsing, but I'm trying to switch to Safari because I noticed that Chrome uses more battery and read some articles about it too.

I would really appreciate it if you tell me of any way to add an option to the right click context menu in Safari to open in a private window, or a keyboard shortcut so that you click while pressing some keys and it opens in private mode, or maybe an extension that adds this functionality.

Comment: In Safari 8.0.6 (OS X 10.10.3), "Open Link In New Private Tab" and "Open Link In New Private Window" are right-click options, but only if the link is in a Private window/tab. I keep Safari set to open in Private, and always use private windows/tabs, unless I specifically need a non-private window (for example, to save a new password into Keychain). Not a direct answer for your question, but it's an option.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Safari 9.0 (El Capitano) you can **right-click on the URL while holding down the option key** and you then have the option to open the URL in a new private window. This option is provided from regular or private windows, unlike what appears to be the case in previous versions of Safari.

[image: OPTION-RIGHT CLICK in Safari 9.0]

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'll upgrade to El Capitan as soon as its final release is available.

Comment: Works in Yossi as well.

Comment: Horrible UX on Apple's part. Why is _having_ to use keyboard and mouse at the same time such a frequent occurrence on macOS? The two should be independently self-sufficient. How hard is it really to list both options in the context menu?